# Google and Yahoo redirect my site to malware, but direct url works fine. Any computer

Tags: redirect, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server’s been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

I can go directly to the site doublewing.org or www. without issue, but if I click on the link in google or yahoo it redirects to spam sites. Swagbucks works though! This is not on a single computer this happens on systems isolated from each other(Try it, avast blocks it) . The site is runing joomla 1.5.25 . I deleted .htacces, put fresh index.php and index2.php files. and still get the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently so. Your web host has suspended the account.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I suspended the account until it's sorted so it won't infect people. I am the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to pin-point for you where the virus is from where we stand. But this is one of the common behaviors of hacked sites. The hack does not redirect users all the time, but only when they come from search engines. This ensures that the site owner — who would have no reasons to search for it — finds out late, whereas many victims would be forwarded.

You can use free tools like [Sucuri](http://sucuri.net/) to assist you in finding the virus.

If all else fails, you may wish to consult a security firm who specializes in such matters.